# A video poem/story about a stranded astronaut digesting himself

Tags: story-identification, horror, animation, poem

This only recently came back up in my memory, and for the life of me I cannot find it anywhere.

The video consisted of an increasingly worrying situation based around an astronaut, I believe male, who detailed his journey aimlessly wandering a desolate planet, and how his advanced life support system is digesting/converting his "non-primary organs" into energy to sustain his survival.

It culminates in him losing his sight, and eventually whole person. Seriously cannot find anything resembling this anywhere, would absolutely love the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This describes a *comic*, [The Suit](https://www.badspacecomics.com/post/the-suit) by Scott Base, exactly.

> And finally my eyes. So I never know if we make it home.

There are several animated versions on YouTube; [this one](https://youtu.be/LjpyTE0Idjk) appears to be from the author.

Comment: The Iain M. Banks short story The Descendant (from The State Of The Art collection) is similar and I wouldn't be surprised if it was the inspiration for this, but the ending is different.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly it. I wasn't expecting my question to be resolved so quickly, so thank you sincerely.